# jquery.get not working net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, geo

I am getting this error with ipinfo doing a jquery call.

`jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 GET http://ipinfo.io/?callback=jQuery1124031570803364791034_1511997975801&_=1511997975802 net::ERR_ABORTED`

jQuery

```
jQuery.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
   if (response.country === "AU"){
   jQuery("a.my_link").attr("href","http://example.com.au");
      } else if(response.country === "US"){
   jQuery("a.my_link").attr("href","http://example.us");
      } else {
   jQuery("a.my_link").attr("href","http://example.com.au");
}
}, "jsonp");
```

html

```
<a id="my_link" class="my_link" href="#" target="_blank" title="my-logo"><button class="btn btn-primary pull-left my-logo"  alt="my" ><?php echo get_theme_mod(  'my_label', '' ); ?></button></a>
```

Comment: Got an ad-blocker extension?

Comment: Nah do not have adblock extension. thx

Comment: It tried it on jsfiddle, which uses `https`. When I changed the url to `https://ipinfo.io` it worked.

Comment: It started working again (http). I believe it could be ipinfo.io that had issues - I am not entirely sure. But I will put in https and see if this problem replicates itself. Cheers!